# R post-hoc test brms

Tags: r, bayesian, posthoc, emmeans

I have the following model:

```
prior1 <- c(
  prior(normal(0, 50), class = b),
  prior(exponential(0.1), class = sd),
  prior(exponential(0.1), class = sigma))

BMvpa <- brm (
  RT ~ 1 + GroupC*PrimeC*CongC*EmoC*SexC
  + (1 + CongC *PrimeC*EmoC || ID) 
  + (1 + GroupC*PrimeC*CongC*EmoC*SexC || Target),
  data = df1,
  family = exgaussian(),
  prior = prior1,
  warmup = 2000, iter = 5000,
  chains = 3,
  cores= parallel::detectCores(),
  sample_prior = TRUE
)
```

Here is part of my output:

```
                                   Predictors Estimate     SE   Lower   Upper  Rhat   BF01
1                                   Intercept  700.175 13.470 674.330 726.617 1.000   <NA>
2                                       Group   49.027 33.542 -17.261 115.122 1.000   0.51
3                                       Prime  -12.197  2.816 -17.799  -6.655 1.000  0.017
4                                  Congruency  -15.879  2.798 -21.507 -10.435 1.001 <0.001
5                                     Emotion   17.092  6.860   3.740  30.373 1.000   0.32
6                                         Sex    5.362 24.381 -42.347  52.871 1.001  2.031
...
21                    Group x Prime x Emotion   22.339  8.509   5.464  39.136 1.001   0.24
...
```

Each variable (Group, Sex, Prime, Congruency , Emotion) is dichotomous and coded -0.5 (TD, M, LSF, ICG, Joy), +0.5 (ASD, F, HSF, CG, Anger).

I would like to go more in details in the interaction Group x Prime x Emotion (represented on the figure) and would like to know  the posterior distribution regarding the effect of Prime for each group and each emotion.

[image]

I thought about 2 strategies.

1/**First using `emmeans`**:

```
BMGPE_emm <- emmeans(BMvpa, ~ GroupC:PrimeC:EmoC)
BMGPE_fac <- update(BMGPE_emm, levels =list(GroupC= c("TD","ASD"), PrimeC= c("LSF","HSF"), EmoC=c("joy","anger")))
contRT1 <- as.data.frame(contrast(BMGPE_fac, method = "pairwise", by = c("GroupC","EmoC")))
```

Output:

```
1 LSF - HSF     TD   joy  8.706978 -0.3446188  18.33661
2 LSF - HSF    ASD   joy 20.487280 10.2622944  30.46115
3 LSF - HSF     TD anger 15.029082  6.2702713  24.67623
4 LSF - HSF    ASD anger  4.412052 -5.6749680  14.60393
```

I am not sure about this because I would have expected only negative estimates (HSF primes reducing response time).
Additionally, is there a possibility to compute a Bayes factor here?

2/ **Second, using the `hypothesis`function** (I read the [blogpost](https://vuorre.netlify.app/post/2020/02/06/how-to-calculate-contrasts-from-a-fitted-brms-model/) of Matti Vuorre). I think it would be the best but the result I got are even more strange and I think I probably made a mistake (I was expected only negative estimates) :

```
> hypothesis(BMvpa,c(qAJ = "PrimeC + 0.5*GroupC - 0.5*EmoC = 0"))
Hypothesis Tests for class b:
  Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1        qAJ     3.77     17.35   -30.51    37.79       3.56      0.78     
---

> hypothesis(BMvpa,c(qAA = "PrimeC + 0.5*GroupC + 0.5*EmoC = 0"))
Hypothesis Tests for class b:
  Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1        qAA    20.86     17.46   -13.54    55.14       1.63      0.62     
---

> hypothesis(BMvpa,c(qTJ = "PrimeC - 0.5*GroupC - 0.5*EmoC = 0"))
Hypothesis Tests for class b:
  Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1        qTJ   -45.26     17.34   -78.93   -10.78       0.15      0.13    *
---

> hypothesis(BMvpa,c(qTA = "PrimeC - 0.5*GroupC - 0.5*EmoC = 0"))
Hypothesis Tests for class b:
  Hypothesis Estimate Est.Error CI.Lower CI.Upper Evid.Ratio Post.Prob Star
1        qTA   -45.26     17.34   -78.93   -10.78       0.15      0.13    *
---
```

So my question is: how could I have the posterior distribution for the efefct of prime in each subgroup (and BF).

Comment: If I look at the plot, in each of the four cases, LSF (red) is slightly greater than HSF (green), so I am not surprised that all the LSF-HSF differences are positive. If you expect otherwise, your data tell a different story.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes,I think you are right. Actually, I was expected a negative estimate as for me, the estimate should have been the slope between LSF and HSF in each condition (so a negative slope if LSF are higher than HSF, as in my main effect). But I realize that with emmeans, the estimate is the difference, isn't it (so positive if LSF are higher). I am right?

Comment: Yes. You could use `"revpairwise"` to get the differences the other way around.